# WebStorm (PhpStorm / IntelliJ IDEA) how to extend autocomplete with custom data.json

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there any way to extend autocomplete for JetBrains IDEs with custom data?

I have `./node_modules/my_ui_kit/variables.js` imported via `postcss-simple-vars` to my `postcss.config.js` and I want suggestions based on that variables in `*.css` files

I am able to generate those variables in `json` with custom syntax if that could help

Comment: No way, the IDE will only complete variables from `.css` files

Comment: @lena quite sad that they don't support this yet I see variety of issues related to `postcss-simple-vars` https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24368